# How to auto-forward telegram invoice to a linked group?

Tags: telegram-bot

I have a telegram channel and a discussion group linked to this channel.
When my bot posts regular messages to the channel, everything works fine. Those messages appear in the discussion group.

However, when the bot posts an invoice, it doesn't appear in the discussion group.
Is there a way to auto-forward invoices to the discussion group as well?